# Is it possible to simultaneously scroll horizontaly two windows?

Tags: buffers, scrolling

Emacs 27.1

If I want to simultaneously scroll vertically two windows I use

```
M-x scroll-all-mode
```

OK. But this scrolls windows vertically.

But I need to scroll both windows **horizontally**. Is it possible?

Comment: you might easily add such functionality to master-mode? https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/master.el

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the definition of `scroll-all-mode`, you will find that it simply adds a `post-command-hook` that calls `scroll-all-check-to-scroll`.

Inspecting the `scroll-all-check-to-scroll`, we find that it simply dispatches to a 'scroll-all' version of the 'current command'.

So we can simply add `sroll-all` versions of the horizontal scrolling functions and extend the `scroll-all-check-to-scroll` to dispatch for those commands also.

Here follows an example for how to extend `scroll-all` functionality with `forward-char`:

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load 'scroll-all
  (defun scroll-forward-all (arg)
    "Forward char in all visible windows.
ARG is like in `end-of-buffer'."
    (interactive "P")
    (scroll-all-function-all 'forward-char arg))

  (defun scroll-all-check-to-scroll ()
    "Check `this-command' to see if a scroll is to be done."
    (cond ((eq this-command 'next-line)
           (call-interactively 'scroll-all-scroll-down-all))
          ((eq this-command 'previous-line)
           (call-interactively 'scroll-all-scroll-up-all))
          ((memq this-command '(scroll-up scroll-up-command))
           (call-interactively 'scroll-all-page-down-all))
          ((memq this-command '(scroll-down scroll-down-command))
           (call-interactively 'scroll-all-page-up-all))
          ((eq this-command 'beginning-of-buffer)
           (call-interactively 'scroll-all-beginning-of-buffer-all))
          ((eq this-command 'end-of-buffer)
           (call-interactively 'scroll-all-end-of-buffer-all))
          ((eq this-command 'forward-char)
           (call-interactively 'scroll-forward-all)))))
```

You can extend for other scrolling functions in a similar way.

You can use `C-h k` to lookup the command bound to a key.

Comment: It's cool. Emacs 4ever :-)